# How can I install MySQL client on 10.04?

Tags: software-installation, mysql

How can I install MySQL client in Ubuntu?

I have already installed MySQL 5.1 binary on server.

I am not able to find the right package for `apt-get`.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

Or alternatively:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql\*
```

Commands like those worked for me when I installed it on my 11.04 system.

Comment: thnaks...... it worked for me with little modificaiton.sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.1

Answer (score 2):

The above has not worked for me. I installed MySQL client with the following ;

`apt install mariadb-client-10.5`