# Where is my downloaded software

Tags: mysql, installed-programs

I have just downloaded and installed MySQL Server from download centre.

It says it is installed but where is it?

I have looked in all the usual places

any help appreciated

Comment: Please help us help you by elaborating on your question. Are you looking for where it was installed or where the package was downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

If you've just installed MySQL from software center, It won't be shown in the menu as usual with other softwares !
Its like the packages and plugins !
So if you need the MySQL clients, Then try using this tip:
(I don't know if this works or not But try this)

**Steps**

- Open up the Terminal emulator by Pressing Ctrl+Alt+T together. Or from menu
- Follow the steps

First of all we need to install MySQL (Just do this even if you've done it before.If you have, Then you won't have to wait for it to download.If you haven't it will be downloaded)

Type this code to install MySQL Client

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

And press enter...
You will see the results...
After that, type this code and press enter,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will update the current repositories of all packages installed !
And I hope this works !
It seems to be worked in this question : [How to install MySQL client on UBUNTU 10.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223012/how-to-install-mysql-client-on-10-04)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the installed location of my-sql, such that where it was installed then type

> whereis mysql or which mysql

if you want to know where you have downloaded the file then first type

> "updatedb" and then "locate mysql"

The "locate" command will tell you all the files named as mysql.

Hope this helps.